# Why are Ahimelech and Abiathar reversed in 2 Sam. 8:17?

Tags: old-testament, textual-discrepancies, 1-samuel, 2-samuel

In `1 Samuel 22:20-23`, we see that Ahimelech was killed by the order of Saul and his son Abiathar escaped:

> 20 But one son of Ahimelech the son of Ahitub, named Abiathar, escaped
>   and fled after David. 21 Abiathar told David that Saul had killed the
>   priests of the LORD. 22 Then David said to Abiathar, “I knew on that
>   day, when Doeg the Edomite was there, that he would surely tell Saul.
>   I have brought about the death of every person in your father’s
>   household. 23 “Stay with me; do not be afraid, for he who seeks my
>   life seeks your life, for you are safe with me.”

However, in `2 Samuel 8:17`, Ahimelech is referenced as one of David's priests, and the *son* of Abiathar:

> 17 and Zadok the son of Ahitub and Ahimelech the son of Abiathar were priests, and Seraiah was secretary,

Obviously both can't be true, but I can't seem to find any compelling information that would explain this reversal of names.

Comment: See this question at BH.SE: [Was Abiathar the son of Ahimelech or was Ahimelech the son of Abiathar?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/2955/2757)

Answer (score 1):

I have a list of alleged Biblical contradictions that contains this question.

1. We must first attempt to establish a reference point in time for these verses.

   - 1 Samuel 22:20-23 occurred before David ascended to the throne.  King Saul was then in pursuit of David, and had recently ordered the deaths of 85 priests, after accusing them of treason [1 Samuel 22:17, 18].  Abiathar, son of Ahimelech, was one who had escaped death.
   - 2 Samuel 8:17 occurred at least 7 1/2 years into David's forty-year reign [2 Samuel 5:4].

     - 2 Samuel 5:5:  David reigned over Judah in Hebron 7 1/2 years; then 33 years over all Israel in Jerusalem.  2 Samuel 8 was during his [early?] reign in Jerusalem.
2. Next, we must attempt to identify these men.

   - "Ahimelech" was a name given to at least two men that David knew:

     - The first was identified as a priest in 1 Samuel 22:20-23.
     - The second was identified in 1 Samuel 26:6 as "Ahimelech the Hittite."
     - Though possessing the same name, these are clearly not the same person.
   - What, then, of the third Ahimelech, in 2 Samuel 8:17?

     - We know he was a priest; apparently, he was much more.

       - Zadok was not only a priest in David's reign; he was the High Priest--the lineage can be verified in Ezra 7:1-5.
       - This Ahimelech was apparently a co-High Priest; he is paired with Zadok several other times in Scripture:  2 Samuel 15:24, 29, 35; 17:15; 19:11; 20:25.
       - He must have died early in Solomon's reign; in 1 Kings 4:4, we read of "Zadok and Abiathar" as priests.
3. I conclude, though "Ahimelech" and "Abiathar" are named in both passages, they are not the same two men in both passages.  Therefore, there is no contradiction.